# My custom modal doesn't close because of react's useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, modal-dialog

My custom modal window opens up but doesn't close when I click on the darkened area. I investigated a bit and found out that the setActive function in the modal component doesn't set the active to false for some reason. How can I fix this?

The modal file

```
import React from 'react'
import './style.css'


const Modal = ({active, setActive, children}) => {

  return (
    <div className={active?'modal_main active':'modal_main'} onClick={()=>{setActive(false)}}>
        <div className={active?'modal_content active':'modal_content'} onClick={e=>e.stopPropagation()}>
           {children}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

Where I use the modal window

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Modal from '../../modal'
import './style.css'

function TagItem(props) {
  const [tagActive, setTagActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className='tag-item' onClick={()=>setTagActive(true)}>
      {props.tag}
      <Modal active = {tagActive} setActive = {setTagActive}>
        <div >{props.tag}</div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TagItem
```

modal's css

```
.modal_main{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index:1;
}

.modal_main.active{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.modal_content{
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: white;
    height: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transition: 0.4s all;
}

.modal_content.active{
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

tag-item's css

```
.tag-item{
    border: 1px limegreen solid;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(178, 246, 119);
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.tag-item:hover{
    cursor: default;
    background-color: rgb(1, 152, 1) ;
}
```

Comment: If I got you maybe the state of active should be shared between your two components. Have a look here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-update-the-state-of-react-components-using-callback/ maybe it'll help you using a callback to set active to false in TagItem. If this is what is your issue about  solving that way will work for you

Comment: I highly doubt the `useState` hook is the cause of any issue. Is the `onClick` handler of the outer `div` element invoked? Can you edit your question to include your CSS, or create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I've tested the onClick event by having the modal_main log the active property when clicked and it's always true. That's why I think the problem here is with the useState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The click event from the modals's outer `div` element`is triggering the state update, but it's also propagated out of the`Modal`component to the`TagItem`component's`div`element and this enqueues a`tagActive`state update to`true`. The state update to close the modal is overwritten.

## Solution

Stop the propagation of the outer `div` element's click event.

```
const Modal = ({ active, setActive, children }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={active ? "modal_main active" : "modal_main"}
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation(); // <-- stop propagation to parent component
        setActive(false);
      }}
    >
      <div
        className={active ? "modal_content active" : "modal_content"}
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit my-custom-modal-doesnt-close-because-of-reacts-usestate-hook]

Comment: Thank you Drew! So is the child div's onClick function always overwritten by the parent div's onClcik function unless we call stopPropagation in the child?

Comment: @BeastMaster64 Nonono, the `onClick` handlers aren't being overwritten, the click event is propagating up the DOMTree and both handlers are handling the event. One handler tries to toggle the state false to close the modal while the other tries to open the modal. The last state update processed if the one the UI sees.

Comment: Thanks now I understand. Though it's kinda weird that I didn't catch that in the useEffect that was logging tagActive when debugging this problem